# re.DOTALL works for re.match but not re.sub?

Tags: python, regex

Why does this match as expected, but fails to sub? A single line s works fine.

```
import re
s = """<script>
wut</script>"""
print(re.match('<script(.*?)</script>', s, re.DOTALL).groups())
# Returns ('>\nwut',)
print(re.sub('<script(.*?)</script>', '', s, re.DOTALL))
# Returns <script>
# wut</script>
```

I just want to understand this; no need to suggest Beautiful Soup or manual parsing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

4h parameter to `re.sub` is count not flags, you can use:

```
>>> print re.sub('<script.*?</script>', '', s, 0, re.DOTALL)
''
```

Here we're passing `count=0`, which means any # of replacements.

[Signature of `re.sub` is](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)
```

Comment: this could save me an hour